# Python, make attribute accessible to other attributes of a class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a Python class (MainClass), having 3 attributes:

- a data_history dict, which is updated at runtime (the program is analyzing a video stream, so data_history gets updated basically at each frame);
- 2 other objects (data_analyzer_00, data_analyzer_01), each having a use_data_history() method that requires to use data from data_history;

and I need to make data_history accessible to data_analyzer_00 and data_analyzer_01.

One way would be to pass MyClass as argument when initializing the data_analyzer_00 and data_analyzer_01 objects, so something like this:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_history = {}
        self.data_analyzer_00 = DataAnalyzer(self)
        self.data_analyzer_01 = DataAnalyzer(self)

    def update_data_history(self, new_data_history):
        self.data_history = new_data_history

class DataAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, my_class_instance):
        self.my_class_instance = my_class_instance

    def use_data_history(self)
        # using self.my_class_instance.data_history
```

So that I can do

```
main_obj = MainClass()
main_obj.data_history = {"old_key": "old_value"}
print(main_obj.data_analyzer_00.data_history)   # prints old data_history
main_obj.update_data_history({"old_key": "old_value"})
print(main_obj.data_analyzer_00.data_history)   # prints new data_history
```

Just, I was wondering if this is the correct way to do it, since this way I create some sort of recursive situation (main_obj has a data_analyzer_00 attribute, which has a my_class_instance attribute attribute, which has a data_analyzer_00 attribute...).
Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep them separate and introduce a `get_data_history()` function into your main class. This can then be called within your `DataAnalyzer`.

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_history = {}

    def update_data_history(self, new_data_history):
        self.data_history = new_data_history

    def get_data_history(self):
        return self.data_history

class DataAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def use_data_history(self, data_history):
        print(data_history)

mainclass = MainClass()

analyzer0 = DataAnalyzer()
analyzer1 = DataAnalyzer()

mainclass.update_data_history({'some':'test'})

analyzer0.use_data_history(mainclass.get_data_history())
analyzer1.use_data_history(mainclass.get_data_history())
```

would print:

```
{'some':'test'}
{'some':'test'}
```

EDIT:
As @chepner suggested, you dont need to have a function to return the `data_history` object, unless you need to do some processing with it first. I did it anyways, to show how it would be done, in case you need to do processing beforehand.

Comment: Just let users of `mainclass` access the `data_history` attribute directly, and if that proves to be a problem later, replace `data_history` with a property that provides the necessary restrictions on access. Adding a trivial getter like `get_data_history` just clutters your class's API.